# Spring Security with LDAP - preprocess username

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

I'm using Spring Security with LDAP. 
Due to company policies, it should be possible to login with four different variants of the username, all of which contains the userid: xxID, ID, xxID@organization.com and ID@organization.com.

I'm authenticating like:
    .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=person)(uid={0}))")
where uid should be xxID. Is it possible to preprocess the username, such that all variants are possible (while still using the ldapauthentication())?

My entire authentication configuration is:

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator((userData, username) -> {
                ..get authorities from database
            })
            .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=person)(uid={0}))")
            .contextSource().url(env.getProperty("spring.ldap.urls", String[].class)[0]);
}
```

Best

Comment: Within my limited knowledge, I can only think of two variants of username:- sAMAccountName, and UPN.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I would use uid in all cases, simply by getting the uid from the entered username (uid={0}) - question is how to do this :)